# SQLite - Run multi-line SQL script from file?

Tags: sqlite, scripting

I have the following SQL in a file, user.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE user
(
  user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  username varchar(255),
  password varchar(255)
);
```

However, when the following command is executed:

```
sqlite3 my.db < user.sql
```

The following error is generated:

```
Error: near line 1: near ")": syntax error
```

I would prefer to keep the SQL as-is, as the file will be checked into source control and will be more maintainable and readable as it is now. Can the SQL span multiple lines like this, or do I need to put it all on the same line?

Comment: When you tried it, what happened?  Did you try `sqlite3 mydb.db <someFile.sql`?  If so, what did you see?

Comment: Your error message doesn't make a lot of sense when compared with the code snippet you provided.  There's no ")" on line 1.  Can you provide the actual code from `user.sql`?

Comment: Also please notice, that some DBs don't like scripts that end without(!) an empty line.

Comment: sqlite3 has the `.read` command, which reads and processes an input SQL file. Your command would look like `sqlite3 my.db '.read user.sql'`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem.

Then I noticed, my editor (Notepad++) reports Macintosh format for end of lines.

Converting eols into Unix style turned the script file into format, which sqlite3 understood.

Answer (score 28):

I realize that this is not a direct answer to your question.  As Brian mentions, this could be a silly platform issue.

If you interface with SQLite through Python, you will probably avoid most platform-specific issues and you get to have fun things like datetime columns :-)

Something like this should work fine:

```
import sqlite3

qry = open('create_table_user.sql', 'r').read()
conn = sqlite3.connect('/path/to/db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(qry)
conn.commit()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful and succinct code, @bernie. For others in the future that come across this: if you have more than one statement in your SQL file, us c.executescript(qry) instead of c.execute(qry)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Jordan. It is likely to be helpful to future readers of this thread. To add a minor note about `executescript()`: [it is not a standard part of the DB-API](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.executescript), so some Python-database libraries may not implement it.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple lines aren't a problem. There might be a platform issue, because I am able to run this example successfully using SQLite3 3.6.22 on OS X 10.5.8.

Answer (score 1):

Here is bernie's python example upgraded to handle exceptions in the script instead of silently failing (Windows 7, ActiveState Python 3.x)

```
import sqlite3
import os
import os.path
import ctypes

databaseFile = '.\\SomeDB.db'
sqlFile = '.\\SomeScripts.sql'

# Delete the old table
if os.path.isfile(databaseFile):
    os.remove(databaseFile)

# Create the tables
qry = open(sqlFile, 'r').read()
sqlite3.complete_statement(qry)
conn = sqlite3.connect(databaseFile)
cursor = conn.cursor()
try:
    cursor.executescript(qry)
except Exception as e:
    MessageBoxW = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW
    errorMessage = databaseFile + ': ' + str(e)
    MessageBoxW(None, errorMessage, 'Error', 0)
    cursor.close()
    raise
```